# Persistent Query Support in GraphQL Java

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

I am new to GraphQl. I would like to implement the Persistent  query support for my API. I want to know whether we can achieve it using GraphQL Java. We are not using apolo or any other third party libraries.

Would like to know , how can i implement this support in GraphQL Java .
Lets say client send me a query , i would like to persist it and needs to return a hash for it
Then clients can call my API using this Persisted query hash.

Thanks in Advanace

Comment: As per i know Apollo server uses it as ----->
The client sends the hash and the query for the first time and server caches it.
So the second time onwards when the client sends the hash, server gets the query by using that hash as key.

Comment: As per this pull req: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/pull/2013/files#diff-5926af203b6a63ff10e4dbf71869e31f9c1f840e50a8c54df5f09ac7a79075c0. graphql java supports it. do you know how can we implement it . I mean i think we need to add it the Execution Input .. then not sure how to pass the queries .. can you please take a look